# Unable to link dialogflow webhook to ngrok tunnel

Tags: flask, dialogflow-es, chatbot, ngrok, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Have created a chatbot and I am trying to connect it to my local host using ngrok....the localjost is running via my computer and is showing active...however dialogflow webhook is not able to send any request to the ngrok portal...

I have tried multiple time to host a server via ngrok and pasted the link in webhook section in Dialogflow..but dialogflow diagnostic shows

Webhook call failed. Error: PERMISSION_DENIED.
[fulfillment status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8kB2.png) [ngrok cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67GLJ.png) [ngrok server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIqso.png)
Any help would be appreciated...not sure what I am missing....

Comment: It is very difficult to help diagnose your problem without seeing concrete information. If you can update your question with the exact error message and where you're seeing this message, the code you're running on your computer, screen shots of the Dialogflow webhook configuration, and the ngrok screen, we have a better chance of helping you. (If you're concerned about security, you can run ngrok to take the pictures and then kill it, so the host will change for next time.)

Comment: Hi I have added few images for your reference....happy to provide any more details needed...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual configuration, there are a few things I would look at:

- Make sure you're actually using the right ngrok URL from your console. Many times I was using an older URL in the Dialogflow configuration.
- Make sure you're using the HTTPS URL.
- Make sure your server is actually running on your computer, and that it is listening at the same port that ngrok is using on your computer.
- Check the ngrok console to see if it is getting the request at all and what the response might be.
- Go to http://localhost:4040/ which will give you details of each connection through ngrok.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I have been using the updated link everytime... Dialogflow is not allowing me to use HTTPS link...only HTTP....server is running on my system ngrok status is online...and the port are correct...It is not receiveng any request from the Dialogflow fulfillment ...

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify what you mean by "Dialogflow is not allowing me to use HTTPS link"? Showing your webhook configuration in Dialogflow may also help us.